# how to makeup username:password pair in .htpasswd file on wamp server installed on windows OS

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp, wampserver, .htpasswd

I am using Windows 8.1 OS and I installed Wamp server ...i google and found that " it should very rarely be edited by hand. There is a special program on a *nix machine that is designed to manipulate the .htpasswd file on your behalf. "

so my question is how to Make-up username:password pair on my windows machine because I cant use that *nix on my window

my .htpasswd looks like

```
username:encryptedpassword
john:odn927jw3h!hcj
```

but to make-up encrypted password is never possible by hand so how to make password in text/plain format

Comment: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `htpasswd.exe` tool in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin` directory.

And here [is the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html)

Comment: But how to use it? The documentation says to run "htpasswd -c /home/doe/public_html/.htpasswd jane" but this command showes me "htpasswd command not found"

Comment: It is part of the apache install, find where your OS puts it

Comment: So for all others who are not familiar with the command line, you have to put "start htpasswd.exe -cb .htpasswd user password", without "start" it doesn't work, this is nowhere mentioned...

Comment: On what OS do you have to do this? I dont on Windows

Comment: Also see the documentation link provided above. And be careful with the `-c` option. Read what it does, it will truncate the `.htpasswd` file so should ONLY be used on the FIRST call to `htpasswd.exe` to create the `.htpasswd` file on first use

Answer (score 1):

now I got alternate solution

step 1- go to [encrypted password generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator)

step 2-copy that generated encrypted password from website

step 3-create .htpasswd file in root folder under your domain

step 4-write here your username:encypted password pair

```
/*for eg- john:paste your encrypted password here (after colon) 
john:djfj223dv98vufhhy */
```

Comment: This worked for me. https://hostingcanada.org/password-protection/ Windows path is c:\path\.htpasswd