# to makeup username:password pair in .htpasswd file

Tags: apache, wamp, .htpasswd

I have wamp server installed on windows OS
my .htpasswd looks like

```
username:encryptedpassword
john:gugyjfy6786hgfhfh
```

but the problem is to make-up encrypted password is never possible by hand so can i create  it in text/plain format

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to makeup username:password pair in .htpasswd file on wamp server installed on windows OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630517/how-to-makeup-usernamepassword-pair-in-htpasswd-file-on-wamp-server-installed)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

step 1- go to encrypted password generator

step 2-copy that generated encrypted password from website

step 3-create .htpasswd file in root folder under your domain

step 4-write here your username:encypted password pair

/*for eg- john:paste your encrypted password here (after colon) 
john:djfj223dv98vufhhy */

Answer (score 0):

Apache provides a command line tool for this. Search for `htpasswd` file in the `bin` directory. Passing `--help` parameter gives you:

> ```
> Usage:
>   htpasswd [-cimBdpsDv] [-C cost] passwordfile username
>   htpasswd -b[cmBdpsDv] [-C cost] passwordfile username password
>
>   htpasswd -n[imBdps] [-C cost] username
>   htpasswd -nb[mBdps] [-C cost] username password
>  -c  Create a new file.
>  -n  Don't update file; display results on stdout.
>  -b  Use the password from the command line rather than prompting for it.
>  -i  Read password from stdin without verification (for script usage).
>  -m  Force MD5 encryption of the password (default).
>  -B  Force bcrypt encryption of the password (very secure).
>  -C  Set the computing time used for the bcrypt algorithm
>      (higher is more secure but slower, default: 5, valid: 4 to 31).
>  -d  Force CRYPT encryption of the password (8 chars max, insecure).
>  -s  Force SHA encryption of the password (insecure).
>  -p  Do not encrypt the password (plaintext, insecure).
>  -D  Delete the specified user.
>  -v  Verify password for the specified user.
> On other systems than Windows and NetWare the '-p' flag will probably not work.
> The SHA algorithm does not use a salt and is less secure than the MD5 algorithm.
> ```

From what I understand, you'd need to execute the command as follows:

```
htpasswd -bp john
```

When you press enter after the above command, it'll ask you to type a password which will be stored as text in the `htpasswd` file.